# Is it right or wrong to release domestic rabbits in the forest?

Tags: rabbits

We were running low on money for food...for the rabbits..
My little Snow and Flake.
My mom kepts complaining their smell.
Me and my dad tried soo hard to get enought money for any kind of vegetation for them to eat but we didn't succeed. 
Im trying not to cry after it happened.
We released them into a protected area in the forest.
I just...cant...stop thinking about them.
They might get hunted or anything!
I just can't. 
I mean...it is protected and all but..I just feel wrong and guilty for doing this.
I never get a chance to say goodbye or getting close to them.
Is it a right thing to do? Or is it not?
It's really hard for me...

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong thing to do, if possible go and recapture the rabbits.  Take them to a shelter.  If you can't go recapture them, look for a rescue organization in your area, tell them you are aware of domestic rabbits running loose in an area (you need not say how you know) and ask them to go rescue them.  If you are in the Pittsburgh area, leave me a note and I will connect you with the right people.